# Inferring Generic keys when editing Record

Tags: typescript, generics, properties, record, keyof

This code example is a function for terse immutable editing of a record to set boolean values.

The function should accept a record of boolean values and a list of matching keys. It should return a new record which has all those keys set to true (using an 'immutable' update pattern in which the original record is not modified).

The errors I'm getting are so fundamental that I feel I need another pair of eyes. I must be missing something. How can I configure Generics to get the code below to compile and run sensibly?

```js
function createNextFlags<Key extends string>(
  flags: Record<Key, boolean>,
  ...keys: [Key, ...Key[]]
) {
  const nextFlags = {
    ...flags
  }
  for (const key of keys) {
    nextFlags[key] = true;
  }
  return nextFlags;
}

createNextFlags({
  vanilla:false,
  chocolate:true, // this line generates a compiler error because flags constraint is too narrow
}, "vanilla")
```

You can play with the problem at [this playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgD3lN)

The errored line suggests there's a difficulty with Typescript inferring `Key` too narrowly. By inferring only from the `keys` array, rather than attempting to infer also from the `flags` object, it ends up complaining that the `flags` object is invalid if it has any property names which are not in `keys`...

MOTIVATING EXAMPLE

Although this is a very simple example, the much more complex example I am working on has a similar nature, with an error condition similar to that of the excess property checking here - in other words `keys` drives the constraining type of `flags` when it should be inferred the other way round - `keys` should be inferred from the properties of `flags`.

WORKAROUNDS

You would think the workaround below would create a placeholder for the type of the `flags` object....

```js
// Define Flags explicitly

function createNextFlags<Flags extends Record<Key, boolean>, Key extends string>(
  flags: Flags,
  ...keys: [Key, ...Key[]]
) {
  const nextFlags = {
    ...flags
  }
  for (const key of keys) {
    nextFlags[key] = true; // this assignment is apparently illegal!
  }
  return nextFlags;
}

createNextFlags({
  vanilla:false,
  chocolate:true,
}, "vanilla")
```

However, the approach creates an even weirder error. Hovering over the apparently errored assignment to the nextFlags property shows the surprising error lines  (I kid you not)...

```
const nextFlags: Flags extends Record<Key, boolean>
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Flags[Key]'
```

I have also tried using `keyof` to derive the keys directly from the type of `flags` like this with identical results, even though it fully eliminates the `Key` generic, and makes the type of `keys` fully derived from `flags`.

```js
// use keyof to ensure that the property name aligns

function createNextFlags<Flags extends Record<any, boolean>>(
  flags: Flags,
  ...keys: [keyof Flags, ...(keyof Flags)[]]
)
```

However, it has just the same kind of error

```
const nextFlags: Flags extends Record<any, boolean>
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Flags[keyof Flags]'
```

I have also tried using `infer` to derive the keys directly from the type of `flags` like this...

```
type InferKey<Flags extends Record<any, boolean>> = Flags extends Record<infer Key, boolean> ? Key: never;

function createNextFlags<Flags extends Record<any, boolean>>(
  flags: Flags,
  ...keys: [InferKey<Flags>, ...InferKey<Flags>[]]
)
```

This leads to a similarly surprising error...

```
const nextFlags: Flags extends Record<any, boolean>
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Flags[InferKey<Flags>]'
```

What's the right way to approach this problem, so that the `Key` type can be inferred from the `flags` object, to constrain the `keys` argument? What am I missing?

Comment: You want the type parameter utterances in `keys` to be *non-inferential* (or at least not to take precedence over those in `flags`), as described in [ms/TS#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829). There isn't an official way to do that but there are various ways to get that result, such as adding a second type parameter as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/W4jd7N). Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks, @jcalz I've used the two parameter trick at a cost - autocompletion stops working and defeats the purpose of having the generic inference for my motivating case. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52726 A valid `Key` type in scope from a `Flags` store should drive autocompletion of keys while editing calls which reference the store. Two other things tho: 1) Typescript's inference planning seems less than optimal here given there IS an inferential solution discarded. 2) The error `'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Flags[keyof Flags]'` looks a lot like a bug.

Comment: To be specific, this is the case that seems like a bug... https://tsplay.dev/N55ddN

Comment: Okay, how about [this version](https://tsplay.dev/wQ2BjN) where we use an inference-blocker? About your two other things; I worry we'll digress into rabbit holes; keeping that in mind, 1: heuristics that are suboptimal for one case might be nearly optimal for many more, so that's why they are chosen that way; 2: it's not a bug, `Flags` might be the type `{foo: false}` and you can't assign `true` to its property.

Comment: That works! The inference-blocker approach is really powerful and makes it so worthwhile to have pursued this! This will be critical for me in the future, and looks from andarist's PR that it's a candidate for core support. It's also really useful to know which of the formulas suggested in the issue tracker you consider to be best for `NoInfer<T>` in the meantime. Regards 1: presumably if there IS an inferential solution, then it should be adopted, right? Thanks for the clarification of 2: how narrowing could prevent assignment. I had only thought of narrowing the keys, not also the values.

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance.  (As for 1: it is almost always possible to make inference succeed but then you get the combination-of-all-inference-candidates and often people don't want to see that and would rather get an error.  I *really* don't want to go further into a side discussion about this here. Is that okay?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function, TypeScript uses various heuristics to determine how to infer its type arguments.  In general there are *inference sites* the compiler might consult to generate *candidates* for the generic type argument (via some heuristics), and then in the face of multiple candidates, it needs to figure out how to choose from them or a combination of them (via other heuristics).  These heuristics work fairly well over a wide range of situations, but of course there are cases where the compiler does things the function designer doesn't want.

For the function with the call signature

```
function createNextFlags<K extends string>(
  flags: Record<K, boolean>,
  ...keys: [K, ...K[]]
): Record<K, boolean>;
```

the heuristics as currently implemented give priority to the inference sites in `keys` and not the one in `flags`, and so you get the problem behavior described in the question.

---

It would be nice if you as the function designer could tell the compiler "please don't try to infer `K` from `keys`.  Infer it from `flags` and then just *check* it against the value passed in for `keys`".  You'd be saying that the `K` utterances in `keys` are *non-inferential type parameter usages*.  This is the subject of [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829), a request for some `NoInfer<T>` utility type (presumably an `intrinsic` one, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#40580](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40580)) that evaluates to `T` but blocks inference.

If that existed, you'd write

```
declare function createNextFlags<K extends string>(
  flags: Record<K, boolean>,
  ...keys: [NoInfer<K>, ...NoInfer<K>[]]
): Record<K, boolean>;
```

and things would start working the way you want.

Unfortunately there is currently no such built-in utility type that works this way. Maybe one will be introduced in a TypeScript release someday, but for now it's not there.

Luckily there are various user-level implementations that work for at least *some* use cases.  One is shown [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546), where we use the compiler's tendency to defer evaluation of generic [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to our advantage:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
```

And now we can try it:

```
createNextFlags({
  vanilla: false,
  chocolate: true,
}, "vanilla"); // okay

createNextFlags({
  dog: true,
  cat: false
}, "cat", "dog"); // okay

createNextFlags({
  red: true,
  green: false,
  blue: true
}, "green", "purple", "blue"); // error!
// -------> ~~~~~~~~ // okay
```

Looks good! The compiler infers `K` from the `flags` argument and checks against the subsequent arguments, as desired.  The above definition of `NoInfer<T>` doesn't necessarily work in *all* use cases (the GitHub issue describes some failures) so it's not a panacea.  But if it works for your purposes then it might be good enough.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgewJIDsBmUBOAeAKgPhgF4YBtXAXXJigA8QoUATAZxgEMUwYB+GABhgAuGCigA3LBQDcwYGgCuKAMYgAlghQxlmKOwZw6IAGIAbdgHMW2ANI16jVjBYhMalBfwAKYDBhpzKxEAJShlBEwmWwAaGAAjBARTPRR8aN8YADpsgGsoMBYRUkRUDBwbNKzskvQsW3xSCgpgAEoYAG8M8JQXUSMzSzYSTr8-bMyAwYyAXwy0CJgvbt687gQ0GFWWNpHRsXoBq1JVimIYVwUoWT9Zv10QBUwtfZNAlllZ4B09A363r124k4alM5hEaHYphYUHSfmUAAsEOFzAwRBcYcBprEAERAlAg8zYlrSGAAelJMAQOXYYDk330UEMB3+uyYCAsaMwl1h2n04Mh0MxOOU+mxOLZFiJJPJlOptK+ugZTNegwBGV0TE53IyFl0jH5UIxfjipkuWqgQpg2N1UEYYqtEEeEGS9uxJsuUrJFKwmAiAEJgDKALQh0NBwgAPyj0ajXtlNLkQA)

Comment: This is an incredibly valuable strategy and taught me about a clever mechanism that I'm sure I'll use again in the future. I've never been disappointed learning from @jcalz ideas.